# Optoisolator circuit using IL300

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator

Hi I am building a voltage sensor using Optoisolator/Optocoupler. The IC I am using is [IL300](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf). From the datasheet, I am using circuit configuration as given in the datasheet: [Typical Application Circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru8PR.png)
Since I am using it as a voltage sensor,

Vo = Vin

based on datasheet

Vo/Vin = K3*R2/R1 = G

So in order to get a linear relation between Vo and Vin, R2=R1 which makes

Vo=K3*Vin

Where K3 is trasnfer gain of IL300 = K2/K1

What is the acceptable range of values for all the resistors in the circuit above?
From my research I understood that R3 shouldn't be too big as its to protect the LED inside the optoisolator so should it be 20? 50? 100? 200? 300? 
For R1 and R2 I got the feeling that minimum should be 10k. Again its my gut feeling which is not logical. Any suggestions or feedback?

P.S: Vin is connected to a resistor (of value 1ohm in series with my 235V load) and Vout is connected to my microcontrollers ADC.

EDIT:
I have added very simplified [schematics of overall system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXL5Y.png) for better understanding. Please ignore the values of the resistors as I have input them because thats what I got after calculating R1 and R2. R3 is not calculated.

[image]

Comment: Your schematic shows V+ being connected to the op-amp on the HV side and to the IL300 on the LV side, meaning you have broken the isolation barrier. Is this what you actually built, or can you fix the schematic to show your actual circuit?

Comment: Oops I made a mistake. Its 3 am here and I am making a lot of mistakes. I updated the schematics again. My actual circuit is pretty big. It includes dc dc converters etc but in short its like this. The output goes to MCU

Comment: You still have one net connected on both sides of the isolation barrier (but it's called Vcc now). That means there's no actual isolation and you're wasting your money on the optoisolator. I know the Vishay circuit also shows this---but to get isolation you need separate supplies for the two sides.

Comment: You should refer to pages 6-10 of the datasheet for that device - Vishay runs through 2 examples for calculating those resistor values there. The LED drive resistor (your R3) should be chosen to limit the LED current to an acceptable value based on the max voltage your opamp can output. Their example produces a value of 30k for the other resistors (your R1, R2).

Comment: Ok. So the both sides of the isolator should be supplied from different sources? My system has 2 power supplies,
1. from solar panel
2. from microcontroller

I was providing VCC from microcontroller (both sides). Since I cannot provide same source VCC what do you recommended?

Comment: My aim is to isolate Vin and Vout (same or linearly proportional to Vin) which is connected to my microcontroller.

Comment: Note that R4 will be dissipating almost 300 W.

Answer (score 0):

From the [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83622/il300.pdf), get the maximum value of forward current from page 3 and decide your R3 value. And then from figure 4 in page 5, you can get the value of VP1 for your If. You already know your Vin, you can get R1 by R1=Vin/IP1. Based on what your maximum volatge ADC can read and its resolution, you can get R2 value.

Note: Your Vin looks tooo high. You need to bring it down to the range your U1.

Comment: Vin value is fixed. It can vary from 185V to 235V. Basically it shouldn't exceed that voltage.

Comment: @EEE - to reduce confusion, I suggest you draw more of *your actual circuit* instead of just posting the example form the datasheet.

Comment: @brhans I have updated it with the schematics. I hope it gives clearer prospective